# Explicit "return" inside control structures and blocks in IRB gives "unexpected return"

Tags: ruby, irb

About the following code:

```
if a == 1
  return "a is one"
end
```

When I execute it inside IRB, it gives me

> LocalJumpError: unexpected `return`

But when I put the same code in my Rails application, it runs flawlessly.

Do I really have to avoid returning explicit values from inside blocks? Why does the Rails application have no problems with it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you run this code on its own in the console there is no scope to return from. As soon as it is put inside a method it will work as expected.

Example without scope:

```
irb(main):001:0> if a = 1
irb(main):002:1>   return "a is one"
irb(main):003:1> end
LocalJumpError: unexpected return
  from (irb):2
  from /Users/dougal/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
```

Example scoped inside a method:

```
irb(main):001:0> def run
irb(main):002:1> if a = 1
irb(main):003:2>   return "a is one"
irb(main):004:2> end
irb(main):005:1> end
=> nil
irb(main):006:0> puts run
a is one
=> nil
```

Answer (score 2):

There's a subtlety to keep in mind: blocks created via `lambda` behave like methods - their inner `return` simply terminate the **block itself**, but generic blocks on `return` terminate respective **method**:

```
def generic_block_demo
  (10..15).each {|el| return el }
  puts "You'll never be here"
end

def lambda_block_demo
  (10..15).each &lambda{|el| return el }
  puts "You'll be here! I know!"
  12345
end

puts generic_block_demo # => 10

puts lambda_block_demo # => You'll be here! I know!
                       #    12345
```